# Set up my column in Parse as a Pointer from ObjectId in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pointers, parse-platform

I've creating some voting buttons in my Swift app, where a user can vote for a film they like. My app is also integrated with Parse.

When the user presses the vote up button in my app, it increments a count and adds to my Parse database. I have now added some code that also add the film information to what they have just voted for. To do this I have created a new Class in Parse called `Votes`. My code is as follows:

```
@IBAction func upVoteButton(sender: UIButton) {

    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)

    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

        let votes = PFObject(className: "Votes")
        votes["userUpVoting"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
        votes["filmVotedUp_test"] = object!.objectId

        votes.saveInBackground()

    }
}
```

This code works, and saves the objectId for the film the user has voted for, but it only adds it as a String. Ideally, I'd like this set up to be a pointer in the database.

How can I do this from my code?

Or, is there no point in it being set up in this way? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need t set up a pointer object in the class Votes that points to _User (User Class). In your code, instead of setting `PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId` to `userUpVoting`, just set `PFUser.currentUser()` to `userUpVoting`. When you need to set a pointer, you need to set the whole object, not just the object id. Another thing I noticed in your code: make sure that, before the app goes into production, you change `votes.saveInBackground` to `votes.saveInBackgroundWithBlock` and handle the errors.

For example, you would use:

```
classInfo.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) in

                        if success == true {

                            // Object(s) was/were successfully saved

                        } else if error != nil {

                            // Display an alert to the user
                            // Use error!.localizedDescription as the message - it will give the user the specific error that occured

                        } else {

                            // Display an alert to the user - something went wrong

                        }

                    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it now. You make a good point about the `votes.saveInBackgroundWithBlock` - What errors would I need to account for? Thanks

Comment: @Nick89 Check out my edited answer with the code at the bottom

Comment: @Nick89 Glad it worked! Here is a question I asked about a month ago that has an answer on how to set a pointer to something other than PFUser.currestUser(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047697/setting-parse-pointer-to-class-other-than-pfuser

Comment: I actually figured that from the answer you gave me :) glad to know though that I did it right. Very much appreciate your help!